# Converting multipath devices to its equivalent physical disk

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

In linux/unix I want to get the physical disk name given the multipathed device name. 
For Eg: if the multipath device name is /dev/mpath/mpath0 where mpath0 is the multipathed device and is mapped to say disk /dev/sdc. Here when I input mpath0 I want sdc as the output. 
When you do a 'multipath -ll' you get a list of multipathed devices and its corresponding physical disks but if the list is too large its difficult to parse and get the right information. Is there a way to do this programmatically in C or C++ ?

Thanks

Comment: What about looking into `multipath`'s sources (http://christophe.varoqui.free.fr/)?

Comment: 'multipath -ll | grep "sdc", to reduce lines returned, then parse from there.  Show what you have tried so far (some code) for more complete answers.